# trying to setup relay using Postfix

Tags: postfix

I have set up a new server on centos 6 / iredmail/ xeams
The mail server in hosted somewhere remotely.

I am trying to allow it to accept relays from any servers on my class C

when i try to send email from one of my servers to the new server i get in the new mail servers log file

```
Dec  7 18:19:40 rmail postfix/smtpd[25339]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
bart.mydomain.com[216.123.123.21]: 554 5.7.1 <email@gmail.com>: 
Relay access denied; from=<root@bart.mydomain.com> to=<email@gmail.com> 
proto=ESMTP helo=<bart.mydomain.com>
```

I though i had to do is add this to the /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 216.123.123.0/24
```

and then restart postfix

is there something i am missing or a way to debug more??

thanks

```
    [root@rmail log]# postconf -n
    alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
    allow_min_user = no
    allow_percent_hack = no
    biff = no
    bounce_queue_lifetime = 4h
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    command_directory = /usr/sbin
    config_directory = /etc/postfix
    content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
    daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
    data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
    debug_peer_level = 2
    delay_warning_time = 0h
    disable_vrfy_command = yes
    enable_original_recipient = no
    home_mailbox = Maildir/
    html_directory = no
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = ipv4
    mail_owner = postfix
    mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver
    mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
    manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
    maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
    maximal_queue_lifetime = 4h
    message_size_limit = 15728640
    minimal_backoff_time = 300s
    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost.$myhostname
    mydomain = mydomain.com
    myhostname = rmail.mydomain.com
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 216.123.123.0/24
    mynetworks_style = host
    myorigin = rmail.mydomain.com
    newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
    proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions
    queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
    queue_run_delay = 300s
    readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
    recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
    recipient_delimiter = +
    relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
    sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
    sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
    setgid_group = postdrop
    smtp_data_init_timeout = 240s
    smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 600s
    smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
    smtpd_helo_required = yes
    smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unlisted_recipient check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777 permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
    smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
    smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
    smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
    smtpd_sasl_path = ./dovecot-auth
    smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
    smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
    smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
    smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/iRedMail.key
    smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
    smtpd_tls_security_level = may
    swap_bangpath = no
    tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
    transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
    unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
    virtual_alias_domains = 
    virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
    virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
    virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
    virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
    virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
    virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
    virtual_transport = dovecot
    virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

Comment: Please post the output of `postconf -n`.

Comment: Now for the million dollar question. Did you _actually_ restart postfix?

Comment: i restarted and tested again, just to make sure::::

Dec  7 19:58:37 rmail postfix/master[27252]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
---------------
Dec  7 20:01:13 rmail postfix/smtpd[27313]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from bart.mydomain.com[216.123.123.21]: 554 5.7.1 <r@email.com>: Relay access denied

Answer (score 1):

finally fixed it..
I had to add *permit_mynetworks* to *smtpd_recipient_restrictions* in main.cf